# Parse-Server hosted on Heroku acting unusual

Tags: heroku, parse-server

Everything was working fine when I first hosted my parse app to Heroku server. Android client was working fine, even the parse dashboard that hosted on the heroku was showing all the classes and data.

But, suddenly without me making any changes to server or client for every request made to the server from the android client returns

> ... 100: i/o failure

and the Parse dashboard gives

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
>   (Service Unavailable)

Going through the Heroku logs shows the request timeout error:

> ...heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"...

And to make it more weird, it actually works for couple of request after I restart the server or deploy any changes to the server.

I am currently using free dyno with free mLab mongodb as the app is still in dev. stage. Is that the reason why it's an issue? If it's so can anyone explain it to me why because i've another app hosted in heroku running in free dyno which is working all fine.

**Version info:**

- Parse-Server: 2.2.10
- Parse-Dashboard: 1.0.11
- Android Parse SDK: 1.13.0

Comment: Are you creating a user through Cloud Code ? Are you using Cloud Code at all ?

Comment: Nop not creating user through cloud code. Yes, I am using cloud code. But, if how would it be the issue of cloud code, when I'm not sending any request to the server that will trigger any of the cloud code functions.

Answer (score 0):

H12 errors are thrown when your application is taking too long to respond. At 30 seconds the Heroku router kills a request and sends a 503 to the client. The important thing here is that the dyno will continue with the request until it's finished which compounds the previous issue.

You will need to add instrumentation to the application in order to discover which code paths are problematic. Something like New Relic would be useful here. When you get your response times down to reasonable levels for your traffic then you will stop seeing H12s.

Comment: Thanks for the New Relic idea. I don't know how but everything seems to be working fine today without me making any changes. 

Also, just to let you know the highest response time taken is for logout and requestPasswordReset parse endpoints. They are taking 8.13s and 4.13s respectively. Everything else apart from that is taking less than 2 sec. 

So, I guess this isn't the issue of problematic code paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on [Parse - All Requests Receive Timeout Error](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1855)

I followed the topic and it solved my issue. 
I added `"mongodb":"2.1.18"` under my dependencies on the `package.json` file. Try that, and let me know if it worked. (It did for me)

They're investigating this issue at the moment.

Comment: Currently, I am in  mongodb 3.0.12. I haven't specify anything under package.json regarding mongodb. The mongodb was installed using mlab mongodb add-ons available in heroku. It's working all fine today without giving any error yet.

Will look into your solution if I get the same problem once again.

Comment: I didn't not specify anything before either, and I think it's caused by a dependency. Anyway, if you run into problem again, I'd love to hear from you.